# IPython console not showing some outputs but showing others?

Tags: python, ipython, python-multiprocessing

Win 7, x64, Python 2.7, Anaconda 4.2.0, IPython 5.1.0

I am working through some `multiprocessing` tutorials & hit a problem straight away whilst working in an IPython console. The code below...

```
import multiprocessing

print 'hello'

def worker():
    """worker function"""
    print 'Worker'
    return


jobs = []
for i in range(5):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
    jobs.append(p)
    p.start()
```

I am expecting...

```
hello
worker
worker
worker
worker
worker
```

but I am getting..

```
hello
```

Why is the output from the `worker` function not being displayed in the IPython console?

EDIT: When run from the Anaconda command line it exits with a syntax error on the `print 'Worker'` line but when run from a Python console runs as expected if I keep pressing enter.

EDIT 2: Now works in Anaconda command window (I had the wrong Python installed). The issue appears not just limited to this code. Any print statement in any parallelized functions do not appear in the IPython console.

Comment: BTW, SO requires 2 newlines for text to appear on a new line. Use code formatting to get around that.

Comment: And I suspect this I because the program is ending before you give the workers a chance to print.

Comment: You can test that by preventing the program from ending somehow, like asking the user for input after starting the jobs.

Comment: I just tried that but didnt work. The code runs as expected in a Python console.

Comment: Hmm. Sorry. I don't know then.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in range(5):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
    jobs.append(p)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

I suspect that ipython is ending the child processes when the main process/function is done, and the `join` should help prevent that.

Comment: `join()` is having no effect. It seems to be an issue of the IPython console not printing anything that is inside a parallelized function